# React, useState - Why can not retrieve the state value when passing as (props) but can when passing ({props})?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, jsx

Same as title! Why can not retrieve the state value when passing as (props) but can when passing ({props})?

Code example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.text}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

const Button = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.handleClick}>
    {props.text}
  </button>
)

const Statistic = props => ( <div><h2>{props.text}</h2></div>)

const Statistics = ({props}) =>{
  const total = props.good + props.neutral + props.bad

  console.log("total", total)

  return(
    <div></div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  // save clicks of each button to its own state
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState({
    good: 0, neutral: 0, bad: 0
  })

  const setClickToValue= newValue => {
    setClicks(newValue)
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <Header text="Give feedback" />
      <Button handleClick={ () => setClickToValue(clicks.good + 1) } text="Good" />
      <Button handleClick={ () => setClickToValue(clicks.neutral + 1) } text="Neutral" />
      <Button handleClick={ () => setClickToValue(clicks.bad + 1) } text="Bad" />

      <Statistic text="Statistics" />
      <Statistics props={clicks} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I lost an hour to figure out that passing as ({props}) was the correct way. But I still do not understand whats happening, could someone kindly elaborate?

Thanks folks!

Comment: When you use "{props}" you are destructuring the object that means that the argument has "props" as part of the Object, this means you could replace it with. "args" for example and access the value like this. "args.props.good"

Comment: You can use `const Statistics = (props) =>{` if you want, but you would have to use `props.props.good` instead of `props.good` because you are passing the `clicks` object to a prop called prop

Comment: Just avoid naming one of your properties "props".

Comment: oh i see, thanks. i was following some tutorials and they did it like that pairing with my lack of knowledge it became a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is because you have a prop call props.
`<Statistics props={clicks} />`

so the son component gets this as props

```
props = {
  props: clicks
}
```

so when you use it like this

```
const comp = props => {
  props.good
}
```

it breaks or so because props only have prop call `props`

what you have to do is some like

```
<Statistics {...clicks} />
```

now at yow Statistics component you'll get them props correct

```
const Statistics = props => {
  console.log(props) // {good: 0, neutral: 0, bad: 0}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because react functional component has default argument called props that is an object.
To access the the props object we can access by . or [] notation for eg., `props.name`
and javascript also as functionality called object destruction
suppose i have object

```
let obj = {a:123,b:1243}
// i can directly access the object property by destructuring
 let {a} = obj;
 console.log(a)
//output 123
```

take look at destructuring [--->](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)